# Can <caption> tag be used with div?

Tags: html

I am showing some content inside a `<div>`.

```
<div style="height:200px;width:300px;"> somecontent </div>
```

How can I add a caption that will appear when a user mouses over the `<div>`?

Comment: That's invalid HTML, just so you know.

Comment: You would be best off to do this with CSS or jQuery.

Comment: @TJonS: I appreciate if you can tell me how can be done using css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add a "title" attribute, if you are okay with the browser's default formatting.

```
<div style="height:200px;width:300px" title="This is my caption">Some content</div>
```

This is a global attribute, supported in all major browsers.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global

Answer (score 3):

No. According to both the [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.2) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element) specs, the caption element can only appear in a table.

> When present, the CAPTION element's text should describe the nature of
>   the table. The CAPTION element is only permitted immediately after the
>   TABLE start tag. A TABLE element may only contain one CAPTION element.

You can instead use a title attribute on your div, or some form of tooltip in JavaScript or CSS.